# Creating a string with operator

Tags: java, string, methods, operators, program-entry-point

Generate by use of the operator + a string, that the values in the variable in the given ones on top
Order includes, in each case apart by ",". give the string with System out println (...).

Comment: what code have you tried? what language is this? I assume Java? If so, please add that as a tag.

Comment: Hey yes its Java. here is what i got

Comment: int hexValue = 0xe;
        int octValue = 030;
        long l = 18L;
        double var1 = 4.44e1;
        double var2 = 55.5;
        float var3 = 66e-1f;
        float var4 = 7.7f;
        char c = 'F';

        String str;
        str=("hexValue" + "octValue" + "l" + "var1" + "var2" + "var3" + "var4" + "c") ;
        System.out.println(str);

Comment: have a problem with string

Answer (score 0):

Remove the quotes " and call toString()

```
str = hexValue.toString() + ", " + octValue.toString() + ", " + l.toString() + ", " + var1.toString() + ", " + var2.toString() + ", " + var3.toString() + ", " + var4.toString() + ", " + c.toString();
```

now notice that this will give you the decimal values.. if you want the hex, octal, etc, that's a different question.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we have the following variables:

```
int age = 5;
String name = "Mohammad";
double weight = 68.4;
```

If we want to print them out joined in a string with one statement we can say:

```
System.out.println("My name is " + name + ", I am " + age + " years old, " + " I once caught a fish that weighs " + weight +"kg");
```

In Java, using the + operator you can concatenate strings.
Note: age, name, and weight are all of different types, but when you put the + operator with a String, java automatically convert that variable to a string and then concatenates it with the rest of the string. Hence, if you wish to perform some kind of operation then concatenate, then you should make use of parentheses ():

```
System.out.println("Two Plus Five is = " + (2 + 5));
```